# #NAME! Error with UDF functions previously working

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook macro template (.xltm), with a number of VBA UDF used througout the sheets; nothing big or complex. The functions are declared Public and are saved in a module in the same workbook.
The template has been used for years, creating workbooks (.xlsm) in which the functions have always worked perfectly.
Now, opening the template to make some upgrades, I found ugly #NAME! errors in every cell containing one of my UDFs; if I try to insert a function in a cell, I do not find my functions listed with the Excel ones anymore.
The only thing changed in my Excel is the version, now 2019 64 bit; the template was created with the 2016 version (32 bit but worked with 64 bit also) and, I repeat, all things have always worked perfectly.
Maybe an Excel Guru can give me a hint to resolve this strange problem?

Edit an example as requested:

As I said, my functions are very simple and don't call any API code: for example, I have these two:

```
Const MinValue = 0.00001
Const NullValue = -999

Public Function IsZero(r As Range) As Boolean
   'check the cell value, and returns True if the value is <= MinValue
   If IsEmpty(r.Cells(1, 1)) Then
      IsZero = True
   ElseIf IsNumeric(r.Cells(1, 1)) Then
      IsZero = (r.Cells(1, 1) <= Zero)
   End If
End Function

Public Function Zero() As Double
   ' Simply returns the MinValue value.
   Zero = MinValue
End Function
```

Comment: Hint: [Edit] your question and add the code of the UDF and how you call it (formula). We can't help if we don't see it. Reading [mcve] might help to improve your question.

Comment: did it ever worked with the new Excel installation? what is macro security setting?

Comment: hi, do u have somekind of Declare ? in 64 bit u have to add the word PtrSafe, like Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

Comment: @buran Macro security is set to Enable all macros, and Trust access to the VBA project object model

Comment: How do you cal these functions? Please show the formula you used to produce the `#NAME` error.

Comment: the call is, for example:  =IF(IsZero([@L]);NV();[@L]), where NV() is another function that simply returns the const NullValue. Remember, the workbook has worked perfectly for years, without any change

Comment: A simple check is to do a full build calculation on the file. CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+F9 will do this in the user interface and `Application.CalculationFullRebuild` will do this in VBA. If it doesn't work after doing this, then something else is going wrong. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation

Comment: @AJD Thank you very much, your advice did the trick! You have entered your reply as a comment, how can I mark it as a correct answer? However, the Guru Excel medal is yours ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel sometimes has an issue 'remembering' the dependency chains for its calculations. A symptom of this is when a known functioning file has strange errors in cells that you know should have values.

A quick way to check if this is the case is to do a full rebuild of the dependency chain. From the keyboard this is CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+F9. If you find this is happening on a regular basis, you can put the following line into your `Workbook_Open` event:

```
Application.CalculationFullRebuild
```

Further suggested readings are:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculatefullrebuild