# Cannot call user defined function without getting a NAME error

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I use the following VBA code, installed on a Standard Module, to count cells with a specific text color:

```
Public Function CountColour(pRange1 As Range, pRange2 As Range) As Double
Application.Volatile
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In pRange1
    If rng.Font.Color = pRange2.Font.Color Then
        CountColour = CountColour + 1
    End If
Next
End Function
```

This is how I call the function:

```
=CountColour(A1:A100;B1)
```

It used to work just fine, on Office 2016.
However, on Office 360, it no longer works.

Based on similar posts, here on SO, I already tried to do a [full rebuild of the dependency chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56239977/name-error-with-udf-functions-previously-working), and I have checked if there is any [module with the same name as the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830181/name-error-in-excel-for-vba-function).

Nothing works, so far. Can anyone help me figuring this out?

Comment: Works fine on my end (365 Monthly channel)

Comment: The UDF must be installed in a **Standard Module** .  The `Name` error means VBA can't "see" the UDF.

Comment: @Gary's Student It is installed in a Standard Module. It used to work until I switched to Office 360.

Comment: instead of defining a "range" (rng), I would use "cell" - for each cell in Prange1; of course then also change the if-clause.

Comment: @Max Just tried both things. None makes it work.

Comment: Open a new workbook in safe mode; then install the UDF into a standard module and see if it works.  If it does, then there's probably duplicate name in some add-in.  Oh, and did you check that the module itself does not have the same name as the function?